# blender bones are not working in unity

Tags: armature, unity, .fbx

I created a pants model, and bones for it in a blender. Bones work in blender, but when I import it to Unity, they are not doing anything.

I used automatic weights when I was rigging.

Blender: 
[image]

Unity:
[image]

Model: https://ufile.io/gd6vz

Comment: You should do all your animations in Blender and export them to unity. Unity isn't made for character animation.

Comment: Am I writing that I need moving bones for animations? I need a way to dynamically in-game move bones. Cloth bones will follow character bones.

Comment: Plesse add more information then, I'm not a fortune teller. Also: it was a comment, not an answer. Which format do you use for your assets? Maybe it is better to ask in a unity forum, there must be tons of tutorials on how to get armatures from Blender to Unity.

Comment: I posted a model, and I use the .fbx format as you can deduce from my question tag.

Comment: Usually, my models with armature work in unity too, but this don't, and I completely don't know why.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with both fbx and blender files in unity.

Comment: Like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FCqnx75HBs worked for me, so if following this tut doesnt work for you, you would has to be more specific. Also original Q is hard to say something.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem that happens when you export from blender and import to unity. The solution is simple. Open the .blend file and clear the scale by pressing Alt+S. This does most of the stuff but you could face some minor issues. So I recommend also clearing the location and rotation by pressing Alt+G (clear location) and Alt+R (clear rotation), after doing this, export as .fbx and import it in unity. I hope it helps.

Aster17

P.S If you want a step-by-step video tutorial, Below is the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysl0qYq5p9w

P.S.S This link is for versions 2.8 and above but should mostly work for versions 2.7 and above too. I am also providing the link to a QnA similar to your question if you prefer stuff in written format:
[Exporting a rigged object to Unity (as FBX) produces massively distorted mesh, affecting normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212242/exporting-a-rigged-object-to-unity-as-fbx-produces-massively-distorted-mesh-a/212244#212244)

Comment: Worked like a charm; Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. I just like helping people who have trouble in blender.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck on this for days :)

Comment: no prob. I have used unity so I know how difficult it is to use.